# how to login with Facebook with preinstalled facebook app in iOS 9

Tags: ios, facebook

```
(IBAction)loginWithfacebookClicked:(id)sender
{
    // When Clicked on Facebook Button

    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

        // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
        // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
    } else {
        // Open a session showing the user the login UI
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

         }];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this logic inside Facebook button click

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];    
//***Start : requesting for facebook login with valid permissions***
        [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
                                       handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                           if (error) {
                                               NSLog(@"Process error");

                                           }
                                           else if(result.isCancelled){
                                               NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                                           }
                                           else {

                                               //Successfully logged in
                                               NSLog(@"Logged in");

                                               //dictionary to represent the data to be fetched from facebook
                                               NSDictionary *params = @{  @"fields":@"name,gender,id,picture"};

                                               //Setting up the request parameters
                                               FBSDKGraphRequest *requestForUserProfileDetails = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

                                               //***Start : requesting for user profile details***
                                               [requestForUserProfileDetails startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection ,id result, NSError* error){

                                                   if(!error)
                                                   {
                                                       //set login type as facebook


                                                       //result contains the json response sent by facebook
                                                       _socialLoginType = @"facebook";
                                                       _name = [result valueForKey:@"name"];
                                                       _gender = [result valueForKey:@"gender"];
                                                       _socialLoginKey = [result valueForKey:@"id"];

                                                       _profileImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[result valueForKey:@"picture"] valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"url"]]]];

                                                   }

                                               }];
                                               //***End : requesting for user profile details***
                                           }

                                       }];
        //***End : requesting for facebook login with valid permissions***
```

Comment: this is also open a Facebook popup screen.....I want that if user already have an Facebook app then we can get Facebook user details  (if user Logged in) instead Facebook login screen of Facebook app will show.

Comment: If app is installed then it will open the default fb app else Facebook page will open in safari.

Comment: yes.i want this.But in your code if app is installed or not it always shows Facebook page in safari.

Comment: Nope. If app is installed it opens in Facebook app. have implemented this in 2 apps :)

Comment: yes but this is working in less than iOS 9 but not in iOS 9.

Comment: i am using iPhone with iOS 9.1 and the above logic opens Facebook app to login